# Using Database first. My queries are probably in the wrong place

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC4, so some extra explanation wouldn't hurt! Thank you! I'm working on a simple MVC4 web application. I used Database first method for generating partial classes and the connection to my database.

I'm using ViewModels for my pages, but I find myself putting LINQ queries in there when I believe they should really be in the models. I know I should not touch the generated models that came with adding ADO.Net Entity Data Models, so how do I extend these partial classes?

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace LottoGen.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Ticket
    {
        public Ticket()
        {
            this.TicketNumbers = new HashSet<TicketNumber>();
        }

        public int TicketId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UniqueName { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime AddDatetime { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TicketNumber> TicketNumbers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This generated partial class is named Ticket.cs under /Models/TicketModel.edmx folder. So do I want to continue building on the partial class in another folder somehow, or use another filename in the /Models folder?

Or... should I have added the ADO.net Entity Data Model in another folder called "DAL" for data access layer then continue the partial classes in /Models?

What is the best practice to use here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will answer your question or not.

MVC is in terminology really basic design concept.  By this i mean doesnt tell you an awful lot in practice, such as fat controllers or skinny? view models? etc etc.

This is an opinions based recommendation, as there are alternatives, this is dependent on the scope of the project.

Generally speaking you have your "entity" or "model" as your data storage for your project.
So a simple customer class lets say has an ID,FirstName and Surname as propertys.

you have your View that display data, for example i want to show, just the Name of the customer, but maybe its just a full name. (there is probably a better example out there).

our model can do it, but what about a viewmodel?  View model can be used with the property Fullname.  Now we have to hook it all up.  So, we have our Controller, the controller gets the all this info from the model, and hooks it up to the viewmodel for the view.

Now ill throw in a another class, a "service" class as i call it, but it has many names.  This is where (IMO) the logic should be.  Create the logic such as GetAllCustomers() , GetCustomerById, GetCustomerByName, ConcatCustomerName(); etc, maybe you need to write to the db too? so throw in some more linq to do the Update, Insert and delete methods.

add another class, this time an interface, for your service.

in your controller Use "Dependancy injection" to instantiate your service properly, this keeps everything nice and decoupled.  then in your Action, simply call your service, and iterate through to add to your view model.

this is one example, Not sure if it answers your question but maybe give you a overview on how to go about the design.

Comment: I've learned much since I asked this and it is indeed one way to go as you said. I'll mark it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I've been doing is putting my LINQ queries into my controllers and not in the models.

That way the controller builds the viewmodel using the LINQ query and then passes the viewmodel to the partial view.

I would have a @Html.Action on a view

```
    @Html.Action("ShowSelectionList", "Category")
```

Which would run the controller action that creates the viewmodel via a LINQ query and then passes the viewmodel to a partial view.

```
    public ActionResult ShowSelectionList(int? categoryid)
    {
        // Save the selected category
        ViewBag.categoryId = categoryid;

         // Get the categories to display
        var viewModel = (from c in categoryrepository.Categories
                         select new CategorySelectionPartialViewModel()
                         {
                             CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                             Description = c.Description

                         }).AsEnumerable();

        // Return the partial view
        return PartialView("_Categories", viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: I put all my viewmodels in a viewmodels folder.